# How to use FileSaver.js to save text files

Tags: javascript, html

I downloaded the FilSaver.js on github and tried to test it for future purposes.I made a simple html file that accepts an input and when a button is clicked a function is triggered and that function will save the file using the FileSaver.js.

Insinde the folder ofI only have the FileSaver.js and the HTML file.

here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="sample">
        <button id="button" onclick="download();">save as</button>

        <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function download(){
            var save = document.getElementById("sample").value;
            alert(save);    
            var blob = new Blob([save], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

error:

> -Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export on this line of code inside the FileSaver.js var saveAs = saveAs || (function(view) {
>
> -lol.html:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined on this line of code inside the html file saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");}

Comment: On their website example they use Blob.js which you are not including....
<script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/Blob.js/0cef2746414269b16834878a8abc52eb9d53e6bd/Blob.js"/>

You should look at the source of the example...
https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @DanielTate I added all the script that I saw on the demo for good measure and its still not working.

Comment: @Kaiido I added the errors I encountered and I'm using Opera

Comment: Your code is 100% working https://jsfiddle.net/1pr4090t/

Comment: @DanielTate Thats odd Its not working on me.

Comment: Click on the jsfiddle link... this is using a CDN link to filesaver.js and your exact code copy pasted. What are you not sharing with us?

Comment: @Jarx use an old version of `FileSaver.js`..try it.

Comment: Ah you took the FileSaver.js from the github repo. This is intended to be built by a package manager (bower). The built version is available at https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/5ed507ef8aa53d8ecfea96d96bc7214cd2476fd2/FileSaver.min.js

Comment: The link you send works perfectly but the file I have here is not working for some reason.

Comment: You have to take a look at the source code of your `FileSaver.js`, I bet that was the issue. Try using the CDN provived on the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just update to the following and it will work, try the CDN server used for the filesaver in the below demo

```js
function download() {
  var save = document.getElementById("sample").value;
  var blob = new Blob([save], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  });
  saveAs(blob, "sample-file.txt");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/5ed507ef8aa53d8ecfea96d96bc7214cd2476fd2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sample">
<button id="button" onclick="download();">save as</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.